Is having no weakly convergent subsequence preserved by taking convex blocks?
Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence in a Banach space $Z$ having no weakly convergent subsequence. Suppose that $(y_k)$ is a sequence of successive convex blocks of $(x_n)$. This means that there exists a sequence of real numbers $t_i\geq 0$ and $m_1\leq n_1< m_2\leq n_2<\cdots$ so that $\sum_{i=m_k}^{n_k} t_i=1$ and $y_k= \sum_{i=m_k}^{n_k} t_ix_i$.
Is it true that $(y_k)$ has no weakly convergent subsequence?

No. Let $Z = \ell^1$. $x_n$ be given by,
$$x_n = \begin{cases}
e_n &, \text{ when }n\text{ is odd}\\
-(1 - \frac{1}{n})e_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}e_n &, \text{ when }n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}$$
$x_n$ clearly converges pointwise to $0$, so if it has a weakly convergent subsequence, that subsequence must converge to $0$ weakly. By Schur’s theorem, weak convergence and norm convergence are equivalent for sequences in $\ell^1$, so in particular $x_n$ has a subsequence that converges to $0$ in norm. But $\|x_n\| = 1$ for all $n$, which is a contradiction. That is, $x_n$ has no weakly convergent subsequence, as required.
Now, let $y_k$ be defined by,
$$y_k = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2k}}{2 - \frac{1}{2k}} x_{2k - 1} + \frac{1}{2 - \frac{1}{2k}} x_{2k} = \frac{\frac{1}{2k}}{2 - \frac{1}{2k}} e_{2k}$$
Then $y_k$ is indeed in the required form, a sequence of successive convex blocks of $x_n$. However,
$$\|y_k\| = \frac{\frac{1}{2k}}{2 - \frac{1}{2k}} \to 0$$
as $k \to \infty$, so $y_k \to 0$ in norm (and thus also weakly, of course).

Thank you. You can even take $x_{2n-1}=e_n$, $x_{2n}=-e_n$ and $y_k=(x_{2k-1}+x_{2k})/2$.

Do you know if every bounded $(x_n)$ having no weakly convergent subsequences has a subsequence $(y_n)$ such that no sequence of convex blocks of $(y_n)$ has a weakly convergent subsequence?
